# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.examples' (i am just tried to load mnist)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

**I have tried lots of times by taking many ways but it doesn't work anyway.**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_dataput_data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load `MNIST` dataset, you can try this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,5,figsize=(15,6))
for idx, axe in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    axe.axis('off')
    axe.set_title(f'label : {y_train[idx]}')
    axe.imshow(x_train[idx])
plt.show()
```

Or you can use `tensorflow_datasets` like below:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dataset = tfds.load('mnist', download=True, as_supervised=True, split = 'train').batch(10)
image, label = next(iter(dataset))
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,5,figsize=(15,6))
for idx, axe in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    axe.axis('off')
    axe.set_title(f'label : {label[idx]}')
    axe.imshow(image[idx][...,0])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In in tensorflow 2, you don't need turorial package, use:

```
tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(
    path='mnist.npz'
)
```

You can read more : [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/mnist/load_data)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that tensorflow has created a separated repo for datasets now..just import below :

```py
import tensorflow_datasets as datasets
mnist = datasets.load(name='mnist')
```

This might require bit of installing of other dependencies like below: if you run jupyter from your machine.
But on Colab it will import it in a jiffy since colab EC2/docker instance assigned to you will have these preinstalled.

Below were the dependencies I needed to install since I run jupyter from Ananconda.

1. pip install tensorflow-datasets
2. conda install -c conda-forge ipywidgets
3. pip install ipywidgets
4. pip install IProgress
5. jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
6. pip install ipywidgets widgetsnbextension pandas-profiling
7. conda install -c conda-forge nodejs=16.6.1